# images as buttons to open using modals

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am displaying images from my database. The gallery is to be in (n-rows) x 3-columns type where each grid will have a small image. The image is to be clicked and its large size is to be displayed in bootstrap-modal. How do I do this? Can't get around. The images can be clicked, but no action is taking place.Here is the code I tried:

```
        $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","yomadsdata");
        $sql = "select * from photos";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
            $c = 0;
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $path = $row["photo_path"];
                $image_id = $row["id"];
                echo "<button type='button' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mymodal'>
                        <div id='photoframe'>
                          <img id='photoId' src='photos/$path' alt='$path'>
                        </div>
                      </button>";

                echo '
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <img src="photos/'.$path.'" alt="'.$path.'" height="300" width="400">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>';

                $c++;
                if($c == 3)
                {
                    echo "<br>";
                    $c == 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "No photos in the database.";
        }

        $conn->close();
```

Comment: Although in CSS an 'id' is not case sensitive, it is in Bootstrap. Note that you use `data-target='#mymodal'` and `id="myModal"`, which don't have matching cases.

Comment: Oh No. Thank for pointing it out. It is now working.